# Finding the cause of a JVM Crash

Tags: java, multithreading, out-of-memory

For close to two weeks, the jvm of our public facing machine has been crashing almost daily or at times more with Out of memory error
When I look into hs_err_pid24100.log I saw this message

There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue....

I also saw a current thread "C2 CompilerThread0" but I cant explain how it came about.

i am providing the full dump file as a link. Is there any laid down guide to follow in figuring out where to 
begin to look at to figure out the cause of this problem or how to fix it
http://tinyurl.com/jr7bhee

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/memleaks-137499.html

Comment: insert some logs and track your memory consumption between methods or code blocks which you suspect might be generating the memory leak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a machine with 12 GB, however you made the JVM larger

```
-XX:PermSize=4096M ... -Xms4096m -Xmx10065m
```

the perm gen and heap alone are 14 GB, add another 1-2 GB for the JVM and the OS, and other programs and you are actually using 26-28 GB total.

So it ran out of memory.

```
Memory: 4k page, physical 12582388k(1970656k free), swap 16776692k(7036k free)
```

I suggest

- install at least 32 GB of memory for the application you are running OR
- make the perm gen much smaller say 1 GB and the max heap 4 - 8 GB, and exit all the other programs on your machine and it might fit into the 12 Gb you have.

Comment: Any ideas on how to find the process or application causing the Out of Memory?

Comment: Can't imagine how an app can take that much memory, most likely there is a leak somewhere.

Comment: @idmode the problem is; you have allowed your application to use more memory than your machine has, you have to reduce it. AND your system is using too much memory when your application is not running. You can use Task Manager to find the biggest users of memory.